# How to work around a top heavy 401k

Tags: software-industry, negotiation

My employer (small startup, California, 16 people) claims they want to add a 401k but their current concern would be penalties for a 'top heavy' 401k, where some employees contribute much more than others.

Has anyone added a 401k to their small company or found a workaround/solution to this? I found a plan I'd like to pitch to the COO, but I'd also like to suggest a solution to the top heavy concerns

Thanks

Comment: `1.` Look into adding a Safe Harbor plan. `2.` Consult with an expert who works in this area. This issue requires experienced (and legal) advice/guidance.

Answer (score 5):

At my previous employer they handled it by putting a cap on HCE (Highly compensated employees) contributions to 401k to be no more than the average % contribution of all the other employees from the previous year.

Alternately the employer could just deal with the consequences, which according to the IRS are:

> If a 401(k) plan is top-heavy, the employer must contribute up to 3%
>   of compensation for all non-key employees still employed on the last
>   day of the plan year. This contribution is subject to a vesting
>   schedule requiring participants to be 100% vested after three years;
>   or 20% after 2 years, 40% after 3, 60% after 4, 80% after 5 and 100%
>   after 6 years.

[source](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/401k-plan-fix-it-guide-the-plan-was-top-heavy-and-required-minimum-contributions-were-not-made-to-the-plan)

Doesn't seem like a bad compromise